# Jquery splitter save position in cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a splitter between two of my divs, I am able to move the splitter and change the size of two containers. What I want to do is save the position of the splitter, width of two containers in cache and upon refreshing of browser I want to be able to retain those width and positions. Here's a snippet of the code,

```
var separatorPos = $('.content-columns-sep').position().left;           
var leftColumnWidth = $('.content-left').width();
var rightColumnWidth = $('.content-right').width();
if ($.cookie('columnPos')) {
    var cookieVars = $.cookie('columnPos').split(',');           
    var newPos = cookieVars[0];
    var newWidth = cookieVars[1];
    var newRightWidth = cookieVars[2];
    var posDiff = newPos - separatorPos;
    $('.content-columns-sep').offset({
        left: newPos});            
        separatorPos = newPos;
        $('.content-left').width(newWidth);
        $('.content-right').width(newRightWidth);
        leftColumnWidth = newWidth;        
        rightColumnWidth = newRightWidth;        
}            
$( ".content-columns-sep" ).mouseover(function(){
    $('.content-columns-sep').css('cursor', 'crosshair');
});
$( ".content-columns-sep" ).draggable({
    axis: "x",
    containment: "parent",
    cursor: "crosshair",
    grid: [10, 0],
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var newPos = $('.content-columns-sep').position().left;
        var posDiff = newPos - separatorPos;
        separatorPos = newPos;
        var newWidth = leftColumnWidth + posDiff ;
        var newRightWidth = rightColumnWidth - posDiff;
        $('.content-left').width(newWidth);
        $('.content-right').width(newRightWidth);
        leftColumnWidth = newWidth;        
        rightColumnWidth = newRightWidth;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var newPos = $('.content-columns-sep').position().left;
        var posDiff = newPos - separatorPos;
        separatorPos = newPos;
        var newWidth = leftColumnWidth + posDiff ;
        var newRightWidth = rightColumnWidth - posDiff;
        $('.content-left').width(newWidth);
        $('.content-right').width(newRightWidth);
        leftColumnWidth = newWidth;        
        rightColumnWidth = newRightWidth;
        $.cookie('columnPos', separatorPos+','+newWidth+','+newRightWidth);
    }
});     

       But I am unable to get the result as expected, splitter always overlaps one of the div by some 35 pixel or so, what could be the possible reasons ?
```

Comment: You've already done some work with cookies in the code you've pasted; is that code not working, or do you want to extend it? Could you provide a [JsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) where that code is running in the context of some markup, so that we could have a look at what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the position as

```
$('.content-columns-sep').position().left;
```

But you're using that value to set it as:

```
$('.content-columns-sep').offset({ left: newPos});
```

Might this be the reason for your overlap? Offset is not the same as position.

When you're setting [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), you're setting the element's position relative to the entire document, but when you're getting [`position`](http://api.jquery.com/position/), you're getting it relative to the offset parent, which could be the document, but doesn't have to be.

Either should be fine, as long as you use the same across the entire code.